# NPM Install failing with Jenkins, working fine when called from command prompt

Tags: node.js, jenkins, npm

When trying to run `npm install` through Jenkins and I am getting this message. There is a lot of information I can share but I am hoping one look at this would tell an expert eye whats wrong. If you feel you need my `package.json` file or any other information please leave a comment.

```
+ npm install
npm WARN `git config --get remote.origin.url` returned wrong result (https://github.com/DaftMonk/grunt-build-control) fatal: failed to stat '.': No such file or directory
npm ERR! git clone https://github.com/DaftMonk/grunt-build-control fatal: Could not change back to 'C:/Windows/system32/config/systemprofile/AppData/Roaming/npm-cache/_git-remotes/https-github-com-DaftMonk-grunt-build-control-7e4d577b': No such file or directory
npm ERR! Error: Command failed: fatal: Could not change back to 'C:/Windows/system32/config/systemprofile/AppData/Roaming/npm-cache/_git-remotes/https-github-com-DaftMonk-grunt-build-control-7e4d577b': No such file or directory
npm ERR! 
npm ERR!     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:648:15)
npm ERR!     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
npm ERR!     at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
npm ERR!     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:823:5)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jobs\WEB001\workspace
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.30
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.21
npm ERR! code 128
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: As per [this comment](http://serverfault.com/questions/601004/using-npm-install-as-a-ms-windows-system-account#comment746059_601025) on Server Fault, do not run Jenkins a the `SYSTEM` user. The process should work when run under a normal user account, as per [this issue](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/5912).

Answer (score 1):

got a feeling that jenkins user on that windows got the npm cache directory all wrong.
you could set the npm cache to a different directory via npm config.
npm config set cache C:\blabla\npm-cache --global

Comment: Whymarrh's comment about not running the jenkins service as `SYSTEM`, some of us are given a system to work with and don't have this luxury.  In this case, sagie's answer is helpful.  Setting the cache to a different directory does fix things.